# How to assign a local object a new value from a dropdown menu

Tags: angular

I have an array of objects that all have a name property. In my drop-down, I display all of these objects using this name property. I want the user to be able to select a new name from the list, and assign the associated object to a variable named `selectedGlobalClass`. How can I get this to happen?

Here is my html:

```
<select (change)="changeClass(class)">
        <option *ngFor="let class of globalClasses" [selected]="class.GlobalClassID==selectedOption.FK_GlobalClassID">{{class.GlobalClassName}}</option>
    </select>
```

And TS:

```
  changeClass(inputClass: GlobalClass): void {
this.selectedGlobalClass = inputClass;
  }
```

Also, when first opening the component, I would like to automatically select the item from the list in which the `GlobalClassID` is equal to the selectedOption property's `FK_GlobalClassID`. This is why I have the `[selected]="class.GlobalClassID==selectedOption.FK_GlobalClassID"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Form Controls:

**add line to .ts file**

```
className = new FormControl('');
```

This creates a new Form Control. (Angular Reactive Form).

**use form control in html**

`<select (change)="changeClass(className.value)" [formControl]="className">
        <option value="class.GlobalClassName" *ngFor="let class of globalClasses" >{{class.GlobalClassName}}</option>
</select>`

This creates a select that sets the value of the formControl in .ts file to class.GlobalClassName.

**Now: **

all you have to do now is in changeClass() is change the parameter to a string value and then use conditionals to set the variable equal to the specific object with the name from class.GlobalClassName.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to use angular reactive form 
Start by giving a formControlName to your selected field

in your html file

```
<select (change)="changeClass(className.value)" formControlName="className">
<option [value]="class.GlobalClassName" *ngFor="let class of globalClasses" > 
{{class.GlobalClassName}}</option>
</select>
```

in ts file

```
    ngOnInit(){
    className = new FormControl('');
    }
```